# Remove lines containing a number less than/greater than a limit?

Tags: sed, grep, pipe

I have a lot of lines like this, produced by `grep -n`:

```
path/to/dir/file1.txt:4: Match
path/to/dir/file1.txt:40: Another Match
path/to/dir/file2.txt:2: Match
path/to/dir/file2.txt:564: Yet another Match
```

I'd like to eliminate lines where the line number is less than (say) 10. I know I can get the line number easily with `cut -d: -f2`, but how could you then use this to discard the lines and continue piping the rest of the output in full so you end up with:

```
path/to/dir/file1.txt:40: Another Match
path/to/dir/file2.txt:564: Yet another Match
```

Comment: So you assume that your filenames or directory names wouldn't contain a `:`?

Comment: In this case, that's known, but in the general case, you're right, that would be a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
your command | awk -F: '$2>=10'
```